# Iron-Router: onBeforeAction() -> .next() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

i got a problem with my meteor app and i don't know why.

My meteor version is **1.1.0.3** and here is a list of my packages:

```
accounts-password        1.1.1  Password support for accounts
alanning:roles           1.2.13  Role-based authorization
chrismbeckett:toastr     2.1.2_1  Gnome / Growl type non-blocking notifications
coffeescript             1.0.6  Javascript dialect with fewer braces and semi...
email                    1.0.6  Send email messages
fortawesome:fontawesome  4.4.0  Font Awesome (official): 500+ scalable vector...
fourseven:scss           3.2.0  Style with attitude. Sass and SCSS support fo...
insecure                 1.0.3  Allow all database writes by default
iron:router              1.0.9  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
jquery                   1.11.3_2  Manipulate the DOM using CSS selectors
meteor-platform          1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in ...
```

Alright... now we talk about my problem. i would like to protect some routes for users who don't have the "admin" role, that works find. The System checks my role right, but they don't render the view.

**Error msg in console**

```
Exception in delivering result of invoking 'accounts/hasAdminRole': TypeError: me.next is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/controllers/admin_controller.js?843e8c9edbf0891b773aa63a9ad004d1afcbfb19:28:9
    at Meteor.bindEnvironment [as _callback] (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:983:22)
    at _.extend._maybeInvokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:3860:12)
    at _.extend.receiveResult (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:3880:10)
    at _.extend._livedata_result (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:4970:9)
    at onMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:3725:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:2717:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:156:11)
    at _.extend._launchConnection.self.socket.onmessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?d1840d3ba04c65ffade261f362e26699b7509706:2716:11)
```

**app/lib/controllers/admin_controller.js**

```
onBeforeAction: function () {
    var me = this;
    if(!Meteor.userId()) {
        Router.go('signin');
    } else {
        Meteor.call('accounts/hasAdminRole', function(err, r) {
            if(!err && r) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(me);
                me.next()
            } else {
                toastr.error('Not Authorized.', 'Error!');
                Router.go('home');
            }
        });
    }
},
```

**app/server/methods.js**

```
'accounts/hasAdminRole': function() {
    return Roles.userIsInRole( Meteor.user() , ['admin'] );
}
```

thanks for your answers!

Comment: Silly suggestion: have you tried doing `var me = this.next` and directly call `me()` in your callback?

Comment: genius! it works! thanks man, i'm so blind. please answer my question, then i can vote your answer :-)

Comment: Alright. I admit I'm a little ashamed though since I am not sure *why* it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly store the `this.next` function in your `me` variable and call it as such:

```
onBeforeAction: function () {
    var me = this.next;
    if(!Meteor.userId()) {
        Router.go('signin');
    } else {
        Meteor.call('accounts/hasAdminRole', function(err, r) {
            if(!err && r) {
                console.log('success');
                me();
            } else {
                toastr.error('Not Authorized.', 'Error!');
                Router.go('home');
            }
        });
    }
},
```